# SQL query for selecting directory and then deleting all files within it - C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, .net

I need to delete all files in a directory (due to a gallery script that is keeping full size images but not using them!).

I've written a bit of code that dumps the query into a DataTable and then loops through the records. However, when I introduce the loop for finding all files and deleting them it only seems to run for the first SiteID. There should be at least 350 directories to scan, but it only does the first SiteID (all the modules within this SiteID).

Any ideas as I'm stumped!

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = null;
    try
    {
        // Open connection to the database
        string ConnectionString = "server=(local);UID=x;PWD=y;database=mojoportal2";
        con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        con.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT SiteID, ModuleID FROM mp_Modules where ModuleDefID = 16 ORDER By SiteID DESC", con);
        da.Fill(ds, "Sites");
        dt = ds.Tables["Sites"];

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            string SiteID = dr["SiteID"].ToString();
            string ModuleID = dr["ModuleID"].ToString();
            string directoryPath = @"E:\Website\" + SiteID + @"\media\GalleryImages\" + ModuleID + @"\FullSizeImages";

            MessageBox.Show("Deleting Files In " + directoryPath);

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath);
            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(directoryPath);

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(file);
                //File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
                //File.Delete(file);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Print error message
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked whats the result of sql query? What data you getting back from there before you even go to delete directories?

Answer (score 0):

First I would close your connection string right after you fill your DataSet. I would take a 'Quick Watch' at your DataTable and make sure all of your data is there. If its not then modify your query.

Comment: if i comment out the foreach on the files part the messagebox shows it going through all of the directory's (all siteId's and moduleID's) the second i add a second foreach loop in it only seems to use the first siteID

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions while debugging? Sounds like your 'files' array is null.

Comment: its hard for me to run as its on a live server, but testing it if i drop the foreach of the delete it runs the whole way through the result set. there are no errors and hard for me to debug.

Comment: done exactly as you said same issue, its like it doesnt like the second foreach

Comment: Just created an application to mock yours and it works as expected. All I say is start a new project and paste your code in and debug it.

Comment: Just debugged it locally and it works fine, could it be a permissions problem?

Comment: That's the weird thing. If there was a problem with permissions it should throw an exception. Also taking that foreach out shouldn't make a difference. Try commenting out the MessageBox.Show that is inside of that files foreach loop.